# More Drupal coodness: getting the transalated description of a taxonomy term

Tags: php, drupal

I'm doing a simple for loop through the terms in a given vocabulary, these terms have their description in both the default language and an additional. The thing is that $term->description is always returning the default language version no matter which language is active so I guess I'm missing something here since I guessed (appparently wrong) that this field would be populated with the active language version. Here's a bit of the code I'm using:

```
<?php $terms = taxonomy_get_tree(5);    
        for ($index = 0; $index < count($terms); $index++) {?>

                ...

                <div class="info"><?php echo trim_description($terms[$index]->description, 10) ?></div>

                <div class="more-info"><a href="<?php print url(taxonomy_term_path($terms[$index])); ?>">More details</a></div>
            </div>
        <?php }?>
```

Edited to add: my default language is not english, I have spanish by default and english as the second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [Taxonomy translation](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module, you should use [`i18ntaxonomy_translate_terms()`](http://api.lullabot.com/i18ntaxonomy_translate_terms) to get the translations of your terms.

```
<?php
global $language
$terms = i18ntaxonomy_translate_terms(taxonomy_get_tree(5), $language->language));
for ($index = 0; $index < count($terms); $index++): ?>
  <div>
    ...
    <div class="info"><?php echo trim_description($terms[$index]->description, 10) ?></div>
    <div class="more-info"><a href="<?php print url(taxonomy_term_path($terms[$index])); ?>">More details</a></div>
  </div>
<?php endfor;?>
```

Comment: i18nstrings_translate_string() did the trick, but I'm still playing around with it as it's behaving a bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t/):

```
<div class="info"><?php echo trim_description(t($terms[$index]->description), 10) ?></div>
```

Comment: Just did, but keeps returning the same string. Still I'll look deeper into it so thanks a lot.

Comment: `t()` has a third parameter, the language code. Experiment with it.

Comment: Apparently the t() method only translates from english to a second language. Kind of a fail.